# WCF service is working only for initial couple of minutes in IIS 6

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I developed a WCF service and silverlight client, when I host this service in windows xp having iis 5.1, it is perfectly working as expected.

When i host in windows server 2003 R2 having iis 6, it is working for initial couple of minutes (approximately 20 mins) after that it stops working..

i am getting HTTP 500 when i access service.

The setting I have used are

Anonymous access and integrated authentication both are checked.

my service config is as follows

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="SilverlightApplication1.Web.GetData.customBinding0">
      <binaryMessageEncoding/>
      <httpTransport/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<services>
  <service name="SilverlightApplication1.Web.GetData">
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SilverlightApplication1.Web.GetData.customBinding0" contract="SilverlightApplication1.Web.GetData"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

my silverlight client config is

```
<client>
        <endpoint address="http://----/InternalBorrow/GetData.svc"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_GetData"
            contract="ServiceReference1.GetData" name="CustomBinding_GetData" />
    </client>
```

can any body help me to trouble shoot my problem?